# File is already in use by another process

Tags: c#, email-attachments

I have a problem with the following code *C#*, I must email a file generated by a report viewer, however when I send the email the program generates an exception saying that the file is already in use by another process . How can I fix it? I put the code and the error below.

**Error:**

*the process can not access C:/Temp/ordine.pdf because it is already in use by another process!*

**C# CODE:**

```
try
{
    string subPath = "C:/Temp/";
    if (!Directory.Exists(subPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);
    }

    string filepath = "C:/Temp/ordine.pdf";
    byte[] bytes = reportViewerOrdine.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();
    }

    //Invio l'email                
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.server.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress(u.GetEmail());
    mail.To.Add(myemail);
    mail.Subject = "--";
    mail.Body = "--";
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:/Temp/ordine.pdf");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(u.GetEmail(), u.GetPassword());
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    File.Delete(@"C:/Temp/ordine.pdf");
    MessageBox.Show("Email send");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
}
```

Comment: Are you viewing the document when you run this code?

Comment: You need to call `attachment.Dispose()` after sending the mail and before deleting the file. (And maybe `mail.Attachments.Dispose()` too, but I can't remember that for sure...)

Comment: No, I do not see the file @Marisa

Comment: You use `WriteAsync` without waiting for it to finish. Not a good idea.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Why? If it's a fire and forget (and OP doesn't care about handling error cases), then I see no reason to actually await it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen 
I had already tried it does not work anyway

Comment: @MatthewWatson 
I have always tried the same mistake

Comment: @Flater Fire and forget operation when closing the stream without waiting and using the resulting file later? Not really a fire and forget thing to me.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Good point about closing the stream, that is indeed relevant.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This has happened to me with many Excel files, but as soon as I put them in ReadOnly mode, they work. Try this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: This should be unnecessary since the is no need to write the bytes to disc simply to read them back into an attachment.

Comment: But my answer helped him, it just happens in C# and setting the ReadOnly mode works for me, that's why I thought it would work for him. No reason to downvote

Comment: @joemartin94 Just because the code stopped throwing errors does not mean that it was the right thing to do.

Comment: Cool, I'm just trying to help the guy

Comment: @joemartin94 "Trying" being the keyword. I'm not disputing that your intentions are good. But giving someone bad advice is something to be avoided. Writing the file to disc was not necessary for this code to work, therefore it's an unnecessary complication. There's a side effect that files are left on disc needlessly, and it slows down the code and wastes resources. The proper thing to do when you have a byte array and went to send it as an attachment it to simply create an attachment from the byte array.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need at all for you to use a file. You already have the attachement content in a byte array, so just:

```
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "ordine.pdf" );
```

Remove the following code lines completely:

```
string subPath = "C:/Temp/";
if (!Directory.Exists(subPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);
}

string filepath = "C:/Temp/ordine.pdf";

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    fs.Close();
}

File.Delete(@"C:/Temp/ordine.pdf");
```

Comment: What does not work? That is the normal way I do it - and there is no file for you to delete afterwards.

Comment: I explained to you badly, I meant to continue to make the same mistake!

Comment: @RiccardoPirani No, if you simply convert the bytes to an attachment without writing the file to disc, you will *not* get the same error. Remove anything that deals with writing the file to disc.